# Reopen or delete closed (and locked) questions that are in the top results for web searches?

Tags: discussion

It's annoying to find Stack Overflow questions in search results only to discover that they've been closed. The one I just stumbled upon is [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c). It's the first result in Google, for me, for ".net parse html".

I'm fine with the question being closed but could someone please get it off of the site or flag it somehow as not being worth returning in search results. This is actively getting in the way of the very purpose of the site, the widespread dissemination of canonical programming  info in the form of questions and answers. Instead, this lump of stale shit will apparently just sit there forever, offering false hope and delivering only despair and dust.

It would also be helpful if someone would migrate it to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), as it's on-topic there.

*NEW!*

Oh, hey, look, duplicates:

1. [Parsing HTML with c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net) – what's really *awful* is that the question, answers, and comments can be voted on, new comments added
2. [Parse html using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527883/parse-html-using-c) – that's weird; this question isn't even closed!
3. [Parsing HTML in c or c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589164/parsing-html-in-c-or-c)

What's really terrible of me is that I added a comment to duplicate [1] pointing to [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/c-library-for-parsing-html/10774#10774) I just asked at the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site. Maybe someone with sufficient moderator magic could add a link to that question to the original question so that, regardless of it's Google mojo, it can point to a *possibly* up-to-date resource.

Comment: Did that post lead you to the correct answer? I don't know anything about C# but it has a whole lot of upvoted answers which seems helpful even though those types of questions are no longer appropriate for the site.

Comment: Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated. Also, what @codeMagic said. How is it *false* hope? The question is thoroughly answered.

Comment: What would reopening help with? The only benefits I see are being allowed to submit an answer and it not having a closed banner.

Comment: Reopening closed questions may not be the right answer, but the issue is real. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209905/withdraw-questions-with-no-useful-answers-from-google-index

Comment: Am I misreading, or do the body and title of this post ask for different actions?

Comment: I'm looking into what's mentioned in the top-voted answers but it, and several others, aren't ideal because they've been inactive for years. Re-opening would be helpful because the answers could be voted on and  edited, comments could be added to both the question and answers, i.e. it could be maintained for current and future use.

Comment: Do you have any idea how long it took to build a consensus to kill those things? This decision was not taken in haste, and it has been good for the site.

Comment: `"It's annoying(...)"` - that's a bad start for a question in meta. It raises ranting alarms.

Comment: @Renan, it was totally a rant.

Comment: @dmckee, my point is that I feel slighted. Google offers up that question as *the best* result for my query; SO is pretty clearly saying, this is not appropriate for this site, but it was asked long enough ago and voted-up enough that we'll keep it around forever.

Comment: Just because it's not appropriate for the site doesn't mean it's not going to help you solve your problem. Did you even read the answers after seeing that it was closed?

Comment: I'm confused by what 'appropriate' means. It certainly doesn't seem to distinguish between content that should remain on the site. It mainly seems to distinguish between content that (most) users can interact with or not. Maybe I want to do what the C++ users have done and keep good subjective questions open for the community to maintain; like say [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). @eddie_cat, my problem is that the question *is* useful and thus should not be frozen in time forever. *But I can't even flag the question.*

Comment: The rules for on-topic questions were different in the past. These questions aren't on-topic now, they don't fit what Stack Overflow has become. In your mind, does that mean we should simply delete all useful old questions which are now off-topic? If you want to ask these sorts of questions now there's nothing stopping you from looking elsewhere, it's just not what SO is for.

Comment: @eddie_cat, there are documented exceptions made for specific communities on SO, notably C++. I can't find the blog post that described this, but their resistance to some off-topic and 'subjective' questions being closed led to their current not-being-completely closed from further contributions. I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> This question exists because it has **historical significance**, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

**Historical significance**: There is valuable information in there, which will probably answer your question.
But the question itself is not in a good format to fit the guideline of today. That's why it's locked and not a good example.

But still, it contains valuable information to the users.

Why would that be removed from search results?

Apart from the obvious benefit of keeping it, if we remove it from the results, a lot of people are going to ask the same question.

Comment: Yeah, whatever. We're going to keep it around because it's been around for awhile and it's not *that* out of date, so why should it be removed from search results? But SO isn't meant to hold onto anything that might be of value to some user; it's very opinionated about exactly the type, subject, and format of the info that's allowed. It should be removed from search results because it's historical, it's slightly dated, it will become more and more dated in the future, and possibly more relevant info is being crowded out.

Comment: And to address your last point, lots of terrible questions are asked repeatedly and ad-nauseam; that's not a good reason *not* to remove them from the site and related search results if possible. Or so I've been told (repeatedly and ad-nauseam).

Comment: Locking questions also prevents outdated answers from being updated, so it can sometimes be counterproductive.

Answer (score -3):

## No

You can always duplicate the question, possibly attract new answers, and then the new question will be frozen in time if it's not deleted first.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+chart+library).

Comment: God forbid that any users other than those that contribute to questions for the *C++* tag might be able to maintain a list of resources in the form of SO Q+As.

Answer (score -3):

## No

Because some nice moderator could, if asked politely and if they were of a charitable mind, add a comment to the closed and locked question with a link to a more (possibly) up-to-date resource.

[Unless no one can do this; or no one is willing to do this; in which case I stand by my rant.]

Answer (score -9):

## No

Unless maybe the info in the questions and answers *become* obviously terrible?

As-is, the particular question mentioned is *not* obviously terrible *now*, so no one that could do anything cares and ... meh.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ussCHoQttyQa

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, touché.