# Can we delete "Setting up a git repo on my GoDaddy hosting plan"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete, locked-posts

The question [Setting up a git repo on my GoDaddy hosting plan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003885/792066) is not only off topic, but there is [canonical](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-git-on-linux-web-hosting-12391) documentation from GoDaddy, and it is also crossposted on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/26836/180142).

It has outlived its usefulness (now GoDaddy installs git by default, or so I've heard), and is basically stale information. Can we delete it?

To summarize:

- The information in this question is stale:

  - The top answer recommends to install a pre compiled binary which doesn't comes from git (which fires several alarms), only to be aggravated by the fact that the blog is dead anyways.
  - Second is botherline NAA, without the link you still get something useful (you will need a pre-compiled git for CentOS, but the only source it references is the blog, which sets the same alarms as before) and a second step which is setting uploadpack and recievepack.
  - Third doesn't know what is talking about. It recommends building git from source but GoDaddy don't offer the headers.
  - I can't make sense of why is necessary all of that in the next answer.
  - The next recommends using scp to copy the git repository over...
  - By the book, NAA https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035405/792066
  - [This was the only correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536785/792066), something I could have answered.
  - Next one, the link pointing to the binary is dead, but at least pointed to something that didn't seems shaddy.
  - Yet another link only answer.
- GoDaddy has its own documentation of how to do it, [How to install git on Linux Web Hosting](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-git-on-linux-web-hosting-12391), which is up-to-date.
- cPanel users don't need to do any of this, as [git comes preinstalled](https://www.godaddy.com/help/accessing-git-on-your-cpanel-shared-hosting-account-12141)

Comment: I dunno, what benefit is there to deleting it? It's an old question but there's a ton of information there. It would be a waste to throwaway such effort.

Comment: @TankorSmash what effort? It's worthless info since GoDaddy now have [git installed by default on cPanel](https://www.godaddy.com/es/help/accessing-git-on-your-cpanel-shared-hosting-account-12141) accounts, and even then they have a canonical [help page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-git-on-linux-web-hosting-12391), what "good info" is lost?

Comment: [tag:godaddy] seems to be like a [Lorenz Attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) for bad and close worthy questions. I agree it should be burninated.

Comment: Hmm okay. So you need to (A) edit that other question because it erroneously asserts that the question was locked for historical reasons, and (B) post an answer that argues in favor of the question's deletion. That doesn't make this not a duplicate. You're both raising ire about the exact same question.

Comment: Oh wait. I just looked again, and the question is definitely locked for historical reasons. It says: *"This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."* That's the "historical significance" boilerplate, it even uses the phrase. So I'm not really sure what you meant in your last comment... You just disagree with the use of a historical significance lock in this case, which is [what Marcus argues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332078).

Comment: @CodyGray it didn't have the normal "filler" on the question itself when I saw it. No moderator note, nor quotation.

Answer (score 44):

Consider what deleting this question would mean: someone asks a question on Stack Overflow, which at the time was considered on-topic for the site. Some people spend their free time writing constructive and meaningful answers hoping to help the OP and other people in the future.

Several years later Stack Overflow's policies have changed, and this question is no longer considered on-topic, but do we really want to delete the questions and all answers? That would basically mean chucking constructive content in the rubbish bin. Wouldn't that be disrepectful to the people who spent time writing answers?

This is why a lock is a better choice. It effectively "archives" the question. It preserves the content but also prevents people from adding new content.

---

As a second point, you say it has "outlived its usefulness", but Stack Overflow does not "deprecate" answers (this has been discussed many times). Besides, very little of that answer is specific to GoDaddy. Much of it can be applied to pretty much any hosting platform or server where you don't have root access. I wouldn't be surprised at all if there are still people finding this useful today.

Comment: "constructive content" I beg to differ. All the information there is obsolete, because GoDaddy actually installs this for you... so, the actual up to date information is "you already have git installed"

Comment: "but Stack Overflow does not "deprecate" answers (this has been discussed many times)" it actually kind of do, if the information is so obsolete and there's an up to date source elsewhere, see [Should we delete "What's the best C++ JSON parser?"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829)

Comment: @Braiam I find it amusing that you linked to a meta question stamped from the same template as this one ... that you yourself asked. What harm are these questions causing?

Comment: @Braiam Did you read the last part of my answer? Almost all of the answer can be applied to $any_server and is not terribly GoDaddy-specific. I'm actually trying to think of a situation where an answer could truly be objectively considered "obsolete", and I have trouble thinking of such a situation. People use old tech, parts of an answer can be recycled, it may be of historical interest, etc...

Comment: @Braiam That question is not a fair comparison, as it's simply a list of links. Not actual original content that someone sat down for and wrote.

Comment: Locking or closing seems to be interchangeable here. Maybe instead of locking we could close it. So at least people could update the score to indicate if the content is still useful or not.

Comment: @KennyEvitt simple, they are in the way of most up to date information. [I've deleted questions of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15469763/792066) because they were getting in the way.

Comment: @Braiam Why delete a question if you can just edit it to contain the most up-to-date information? If anything, the question this question is about should be *unlocked* so it can be edited to be a better question.

Comment: @KennyEvitt **because the information is *elsewhere***, better, faster, stronger *and* canon.

Comment: @Braiam It's more than fine to include information that is published elsewhere on Stack Overflow. If anything, there's probably few places that are even arguably better than SO. Even if the content on SO is just a brief summary and a link to more details, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Braiam "Not being good enough" has *never* been a reason for deleting an answer on Stack Overflow, except in some very specific situations (e.g. link-only answers).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker err.. it is [Delete the list of random books?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/212855) got the wrong one, is this [Delete the list of random books?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295495)

Comment: I humbly disagree. Since this question holds no *current* value, and in fact belongs to a set of questions that are so off-topic that they should be removed, there's no reason to keep it. We're not the internet archive. *Wrong and useless information can, and should, die at some point.*

Comment: Ironically, [Tim Post's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297970/366904) to that very same question refutes this point rather effectively. Although the question doesn't meet Stack Overflow's strict guidelines, it provides useful and popular information, and that is sufficient grounds to keep it around. Tim also put his money where his mouth is, reversing animuson's decision and undeleting the answer. Aside from that, no one there was arguing that the list of books should be deleted because it wasn't *good enough*, but rather because it's a list and off-topic. Git on GoDaddy isn't a list.

Comment: @CodyGray the thing I'm linking is Tim's comment where he says "I'm not saying we need to have this question, I agree that it's not optimal for many reasons. What I'm saying is, **I'm not deleting another one like this until we have some place to put what useful information it contains.**" There's no useful information in that question. If it didn't exist tomorrow, nobody will be missing anything, *at all*. (In fact, we would be doing them a favor).

Comment: Since when did "preserving reputation" has been a goal of SO? The primary goal of SO is to present **relevant high-quality answers**; preserving an out-of-date/obsolete answer is contrary to this goal, which should trump any qualm about hurting feelings.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you put "preserving reputation" in quotes but nobody ever said that. What are you quoting? In fact the reputation will be preserved anyway for posts above some minimum score.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Sorry... I wrote multiples versions of the comment and it appears it deviated. I was originally answering "Wouldn't that be disrepectful to the people who spent time writing answers?" (preserving reputation being the visible effect of not throwing it away). I see no disrespect, no ill-intent, ... in curating content in general and specifically here in deleting obsolete content. I find it far more disrespectful (to both contributors and users) to bury the useful under the obsolete.

Answer (score 9):

This is a symptom of the fact that Stack Overflow does not have a good solution for out-of-date posts. In theory, someone should just post a more up-to-date answer, and it will float to the top as people upvote it, but in practise, the OP often never changes their accepted answer, and so an outdated answer stays pinned to the top.

Deletion isn't a good general solution to this, for reasons others have gone into. I'm not sure locking is a good solution either, as it prevents people from posting a useful up-to-date answer.

That doesn't mean that there couldn't be other good solutions to this, though. For instance, we could no longer pin the accepted answer once it more than three or four years old (if it isn't the most upvoted answer after three or four years, then surely it doesn't deserve to be at the top). But that's a topic for another meta post.

Comment: "Deletion isn't a good general solution to this," actually, in this specific case is a excellent solution, because all people having the same problem will find GoDaddy's guide instead https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-git-on-linux-web-hosting-12391, which is just below SO's.

Comment: @Braiam You'll notice I talked about general solutions, not specific ones. And even in this specific case, someone could easily post an up-to-date answer with a link to GoDaddy's guide (if the post weren't locked). It's not a SO policy that would should delete stuff if there is a better or alternative info out there.

Comment: Are you saying to post a NAA? What would be the purpose of that? The guide is just below SO in search results, why we must add another hop to get relevant information?

Comment: @Braiam That's another question, but there are whole lot of questions on SO that are better answered elsewhere, we don't delete those, do we?

Answer (score 4):

Stale advice from something that ranks high on google is often worse than not existing at all, leaving correct info to appear higher.

---

The only good argument I've seen for keeping this particular question is that the same method is applicable to other hosting services.

I haven't carefully read the accepted answers on the SO question and [the original  on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/26836/setting-up-a-git-repo-on-my-godaddy-hosting-plan), but the SO answer looks better formatted.

I think the best course of action is:

- move any useful info or better answer formatting from the SO question to the Serverfault question, by making edits or posting a new answer
- edit the SF question and answers to be generic, and point out that godaddy now provides git.
- unlock and delete the SO question

This will require someone to put in the effort to go over the answers on both questions, or maybe to just write a new answer on SF with updated information and better suggestions on where to find git binaries.

If this meta answer proves popular, we need a volunteer to do this.  (Not me!).  Leave a comment on this post if you're going to start on this task, so other people can avoid duplicated effort, or coordinate with you in a chat room.

Comment: For this to happen, SF guys need to be made aware of it.

Comment: @Braiam: That's true, it's would result in some intrusive edits if we decide that editing the question is better than just posting a new answer that points out that it isn't needed for GoDaddy, and a good version of how to do it in the generic case.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we delete it?

We should. It's both off-topic and outdated.

Keeping it locked and around *reduces* the quality of information innocent searchers will find.

We're not morally required or even expected to keep outdated, not-useful-anymore information. I don't see the case where closing, or deleting, this question does any harm – for that to happen, there would have to be any benefit of keeping it around, which so far, no one has, imho, successfully argued for.

Remember: we're giving this question **special treatment** currently by locking it. In light of the [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) discussion, it probably would be "cleaned away" in the near future.

All this is about is removing the locked status, effectively - let the usual community process of downvote and closevote do its job.

Answer (score -5):

## Don't delete it - lock it

Lock it to show others this question is off-topic. Deleting it means no proper dupe target. The dialog for locking specifically says "...but is not considered a good, on-topic question...".

Comment: It's already locked... why is what eludes me.

Comment: @Braiam Yes - and keep it that way.

Comment: Ugh, you want to keep a source of misinformation, which is not only wrong in current times, it's potentially dangerous?

Comment: @Braiam feel free to edit

Comment: How do you plan to edit a locked posts?

Comment: @Braiam I mean this post. And a custom moderator message can be added.

Comment: I frankly don't understand what do you want me to do... I explained that it's already locked, and the reasons for deletion is because the content is stale, misleading and dangerous.

Comment: @Braiam [Edit] this. Answer.

Comment: Why are you continuously asking Braiam to edit this post? He will if he needs to

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ I'll never understand why so many people's only response, when challenged on content of a post, is 'on you go and fix it then'. Like, what? Do these folk not have any pride in the quality of their own posts? It shouldn't be other people's responsibility to fix everyone else's stuff.

Comment: Locking it is worse than deleting it. Locking it keeps bad info around with no opportunity to fix it with an up-to-date answer. At least deleting it rids the Internet of bad info.

Comment: @underscore_d I totally agree. The posts people post is not meant to be fixed by others.

Answer (score -7):

Well, sure, I'd bet 'we' *can* delete it. But why would we want to delete it? Sure, Git can be used to store any kind of file data, not just source code or other files pertaining to programming, but the question body *clearly* indicates that the asker intends to use it for deploying a web site (if not a web application).

How does deleting that question improve Stack Overflow?

How does keeping that question improve Stack Overflow? Let us count some ways:

1. It includes info on how to install Git in 'hostile' environments.
2. It includes info on creating a 'bare' Git repository, which is useful for environments in which a normal user won't be using Git.
3. It includes info on configuring Git in a 'hostile' environment.

Yes, it would *probably* be better for anyone to simply setup their environment to not be 'hostile' to Git, e.g. use a web host for which Git is pre-installed on their hosts, but that might not always be feasible or desirable.

Instead of deleting the question, why not remove mention of GoDaddy and make the question generally applicable to a scenario, tho hopefully rare, might still be on faced by others?

Comment: "How does keeping that question improve Stack Overflow?" would be a more interesting question.

Comment: This seems like *exactly* my point of view. Granted, I'm not an expert on GoDaddy or whatever, but this seems like useful information and I am completely missing how it is off-topic to the extent that its presence is infuriating people. But as it stands, I've cast the only upvote and the answer has a score of -6. Looks like the deletionist cabal is out in full-force today. Not deleting content that was making the Internet a better place used to be the gold-standard.

Comment: @CodyGray have you read the information? Is a straight up "installing git on a remote host using ssh", except that everything reduces itself to "install git", with the aggravation that godaddy now installs it for you

Comment: @Braiam The answer is (potentially) pertinent to hosts other than GoDaddy. The question should be unlocked and edited rather than deleted.

Comment: So then you're telling me that the information provided is already very general, and therefore widely applicable. Thus, the "GoDaddy"-specific part can be trivially removed (if indeed they do now provide Git by default), the question can be made more applicable to a wider audience, and thereby redeemed. So now the only question is, is it off-topic to ask about setting up a version control system on Stack Overflow. I don't really see how, this is a tool commonly (almost exclusively) used by programmers. There is perhaps a bias that you think this is "trivial", but that's rather subjective.

Comment: @CodyGray well, that would be a slippery slope you don't want: How to install <my favorite ide>? How to install <my favoryte compiler>? How to install <my favorite browser>?

Comment: How to install compilers and IDEs is 100% on-topic. There are *lots* of questions about installing Visual Studio and setting up make, for example. Browsers are not, in general, on topic because they are not primarily used by programmers. But web performance/profiling tools are, so installing them is also on-topic. I don't see the slippery slope. (But I'm not a big fan of slippery slope arguments in principle.)

Comment: @CodyGray ewwww, I was thinking that SO was a site for "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: I suspect you're probably trolling, but I'll bite anyway because I'm waiting for a compile... :-) The only people that use compilers and IDEs are software developers, so that satisfies the "uniqueness" clause. And setting these things up is quite practical; you cannot get work done otherwise, satisfying the first condition. Obviously a "problem" exists, or no one would be asking a question. That leaves only the "answerable" standard, which I'll grant is sometimes a problem. But if a question is not answerable, it should be closed. Questions about setting up tools are not on-face unanswerable.

Comment: @CodyGray well, what about emacs? Browsers like chrome or firefox? The thing I'm most afraid of is the "but you didn't close *that* questions, you meanie.". It irks me. So, sorry, but I don't agree with the just being "tools commonly used by programmers" is enough to make a question on topic.

Comment: @Braiam It is according to the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "*if your question generally covers… [..] software tools commonly used by programmers [..] … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker *sigh*, why are you ignoring the last part "software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**", here, 'and' implies that both conditions have to be true...

Comment: @Braiam I'm not ignoring it. Code Gray already replied to that.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker then why are you still making the same mistake?

Comment: @Braiam _"What about emacs?"_  Who says that asking questions on installing a text editor is off-topic?  If [installing vim is on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21012284/4520911), why not installing emacs?  _"Browsers like chrome or firefox?"_.  This, I think, does not satisfy the part about being _"unique to software development"_.  Most people who install emacs are programmers. However, there are many people who install browsers with intentions not being unique only to software development. Both conditions have to be true. Questions about installing are answerable by giving instructions.

Answer (score -8):

After looking at the question I want to downvote and vote for close on this question and I cannot.

It should be closed because it isn't about programming, only marginally about a tool used for programming and mostly about general hard- and software and therefore out of scope. Deleting or closing would be appropriate but I tend to closing it (the historical significance is gone) because otherwise we would have to delete a lot (thousands or more) of off topic closed questions.

Deleting a question is usually not necessary unless it's spam or actively harmful. Downvoting and closing is the usual reaction to low quality or offtopic content.

Comment: "Deleting a question is usually not necessary unless it's spam or actively harmful." [citation needed?]

Comment: @Braiam 'Deleting a question that's obsolete is worth doing' [citation needed]

Comment: @KennyEvitt [Should we delete "What's the best C++ JSON parser?"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829) [Delete historically locked "What is the best way to parse html in C#?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283832) [Old, off-topic, locked, low views, low score - delete?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315898) [Can we delete this off-topic locked "historical" question now that its answers have finished becoming outdated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323733) I'm sure you can dig up more examples.

Comment: All of those concerned "big list" style questions, which we do commonly delete. They are quite different than this question, which doesn't ask for "the best way to set up a git repo", but a very specific, contextualized question.